# Redefine generic type in subclass

Tags: java

Is there a way to extend a class that has defined the class for a generic type, but giving a new definition for the type in the subclass ?

```
abstract class A<T>{
    abstract public void foo(T input);
}
class B extends A<Integer>{
    public void foo(String input){ ...}

}
class C extends B<String>{
    public void foo(String input){
        //.. convert int to string
        super.foo(Integer.valueof(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, but those who know the JLS better might be able to tell you why. But `B` doesn't have any template parameters, `A` does.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do there? Right now, as you wrote it, you'll get an error or even two, as you didn't actually override A's `foo`.

Comment: read the section 'bounded wildcards', understanding those may help you write what you need https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: If you don't require to limit your `B` to `Integer`, you could have generic `B` : `class B<T> extends A<T>` and then you can extend it with any `T` you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible.

If a class is a `B`, then it offers a `foo(Integer)` method.  `C` does not do this, and so cannot be used as a `B`.

Trying to read between the lines, it seems like you want something that *acts like* a B, except it takes Strings instead of Integers.  In this case, `A` is the common bond - you want something with a `foo` method for whatever type is appropriate.  And when you want a string-based equivalent of `B`, you're really looking for an `A<String>`, and `C` can do this job.

A simple definition might be:

```
class C extends A<String> {
    private final B delegate;  // Set up in constructor or whatever

    public void foo(String input) {
        //.. convert int to string
        delegate.foo(Integer.valueof(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the delegate when I thought maybe there would be a clever way around doing that work (not trivial in my real case).  I guess this is the right answer, unfortunately for me...

Comment: I understand your pain.  Unfortunately there isn't a particularly elegant way to write adapters in Java (i.e. "provide all the methods from that class, but with some transformation beforehand").  In some cases [dynamic proxies](http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java) can help.  They *might* work here - you can possibly invoke the `Method` representing `A.foo` on both a `B` and `C` instance since generics are erased at runtime - but I've not tried them in this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
class B extends A<Integer>{
    public void foo(String input){ ...}

}
```

does not compile. `B` must have a method

```
public void foo(Integer input)
```

Further on

```
class C extends B<String>
```

is not possible because `B` does not take parameters.

Comment: This is true, but it's not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: *Is there a way to extend a class that has defined the class for a generic type, but giving a new definition for the type in the subclass ?* I'm still waiting for him to explain what he means.